# changing body background to display image on hover leaves remnant of image at bottom of page - why?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a css dropdown menu that uses jQuery to change that body's background-image. It "works," but whenever I hover off (to the left or right) the id's to which I've assigned the appropriate css changes, I'm stuck with a sliver of left over image at the bottom of the page. My first thought was that it was a padding, margin, or background-color problem. Then that it was related to the z-index of the body. But modifying either has shown no result. What's going on?

Here's a demo with test images: http://jsfiddle.net/dqisv/ty6f1xss/

Here's a screenshot: http://g.recordit.co/S4XJw3UrzC.gif.

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
        <header>
                <h1>Test</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Selected Work</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a id="image-one" href="#">Aaaaa</a></li>
                            <li><a id="image-two" href="#">Bbbbb</a></li>
                            <li><a id="image-three" href="#">Ccccc</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <section>   
                <ul class="social">
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-github fa-2x"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </header>

        <!-- Content here! -->
    </body>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body{
        font-family: Quicksand, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 100%;
        margin: 10px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        display: block;
    }
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    $('#image-one').hover(function(){
        $body.css('background-image', 'url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/96/SmogNY.jpg)')
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
    $('#image-two').hover(function(){
        $body.css('background-image', 'url(http://static.dezeen.com/uploads/2013/10/Smog-by-Daan-Roosegaarde_dezeen_04.jpg)')
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
      $('#image-three').hover(function(){
        $body.css('background-image', 'url(http://img.rt.com/files/news/22/ea/00/00/27.si.jpg)')
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm able to repro what you're talking about... Are you just talking about the image repeating and not being scaled to fit the size of the body?  Or something else?

Comment: Yeah, try to trim down what you're including in the answer to just the relevant code, and feature your question a little more.  We can get the code from the JSFiddle (which you've thankfully provided), but it makes readability of your question difficult, and therefore difficult to decipher what problem you're experiencing.  **A screenshot of the problem as it occurs would also be very helpful.**

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom after hovering on a list item there is a remnant of the old image still rendered at the bottom of the body. Looks like a browser bug maybe? Very weird.

Comment: @AlexMcp – Not able to reproduce on my Chrome...what version are you using?

Comment: Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit), marked as 'up to date' on OS X Mavericks

Comment: Here is a .gif of it: http://g.recordit.co/S4XJw3UrzC.gif

Comment: And inspecting the DOM shows (inside the iframe) that the body has no style attribute, and no DOM node exists to represent that image. Seems like a painting issue or bug?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue in Firefox as well, but I'm using Chrome Version 38.0.2125.122.

@AlexMcp: I thought I declared the body styles in the CSS? Could the jQuery be overriding that?

Comment: I can't reproduce either. Screenshot link throws 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @AlexMcp I'm still a little confused by what you said about the DOM node and lack of body style attributes. Can you please explain?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this in the Fiddle in Chrome and Firefox.  The GIF works for me, though.  Using z-index for hiding and displaying things isn't really the right way to go.

Comment: @CassidyWilliams I know, it's just a really weird glitch. I worked around it by using jQuery's addClass() in place of .css(), but still don't know why the issue even happened in the first place.

Comment: I had a similar issue a little while ago. I found that "painting" the whole `body` of a page with a script (specially a `hover` effect) can bring such glitch. IIRC, I ended up using a `div` to cover the whole `body` and used that `div` to show/hide the backgrounds. 
FWIW...

(It might have something to do with the fact that the browser has to fetch a new image everytime you use `hover` since you completely remove that image on `mouseout`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the image is showing the previous item, it is simply that the background image is repeating because it isn't big enough to fill the area and you don't have any css set for background-repeat.

If you set the following:

```
body {
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

The code will stop it repeating and uses background-cover to stretch the background to cover the whole body. You can remove the background-size if you don't want it to stretch and show the image at the original size with no repeat.

See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp